# Alternative to AddPsSnapin to load Cmdlet in runspace

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm attempting to test a C# Cmdlet's interaction with PowerShell's pipelie.

When I attempt to register the Cmdlet's snap-in, I get an error (`No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 4.`).  I suspect that this is because my Windows account doesn't have the rights to register snap-ins.

Code:

```
using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(config))
{
    PSSnapInException warning;

    // error generated on this line
    config.AddPSSnapIn("PsEnterprise.PsEnterpriseSnapIn", out warning);

    runspace.Open();

    using (Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline())
    {

        // arrange
        Command command = new Command("New-PsDrive");
        command.Parameters.Add("Name", "DEV");
        command.Parameters.Add("PsProvider", "MyProvider");
        command.Parameters.Add("Root", "DEV:\\");

        pipeline.Commands.Add(command);

        // act
        Collection<PSObject> actual = pipeline.Invoke();

        // assert
        Assert.AreEqual<int>(1, actual.Count);
        Assert.IsNotNull(actual[0]);
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actual, typeof(MyDriveInfo));

    } // Pipeline
} // Runspace
```

Is there another way to reference the Cmdlet such that it can be tested in this manner?

Comment: Do you get the same error when adding the snapin if it's not in a runspace?

Comment: I don't have the rights to edit the registry: `System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the registry key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\Power
ShellSnapIns\MyCmdletProject' is denied.`

Comment: Why do you need snap-ins? Them are v1 staff. Snap-ins are superseded by modules in v2. And in v3 build-in snap-ins like `Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility` are transformed into modules. Only `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core` preserve its snap-in status.

Comment: @PetSerAl, I'd rather not use a snap-in.  Is there another way to load the Cmdlet's project so it can be tested in the manner?

Comment: Installing a snapin does require Admin rights. You could import the snapin as a binary module: `Import-Module -Name c:\example.dll`, but in all likelihood that won't get you what you need and you'll need to make a [Module manifest](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/10/16/learn-how-to-load-and-use-powershell-snap-ins/)

Comment: I do have a `psd1` file defined.  Sounds like I need to add a command to import the module `command = new Command("Import-Module MyCmdletProject.psd1");` prior to the command that adds `New-PsDrive`.